# how to write a cronjob for all users?

Tags: cron, antivirus, cron-task

I am trying to install ClamAV, and want to make a cronjob, which does a daily scan, but FOR all users, not a specific one or specific group! for all users of the computer!

How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: It might help to add some information about your environment to the question

Comment: cron jobs can only run as a single user. if you want the whole system to be scanned, then run it as root. And otherwise - offtopic, not a programming question. This is more server configuration.